# How do I fix Object?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-elements

I am using `TextInputMask` to set the currency. When I use it in the `ListIstem` element, it comes with other elements as "object".

Sample code:

```
<FlatList
  data={teams}
  renderItem={({item}) =>
    <ListItem
      title={item.team}
      subtitle={
        <TextInputMask
          type={'money'}
          options={{ precision: 2, separator: ',', delimiter: '.', unit: '' }}
          value={parseFloat(item.amount)}
        /> + 'Count: ' + item.count
      }
      bottomDivider={true}
    />
  }
  keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
/>
```

Output;

```
[object Object] Count: 6
``
```

Comment: can you add what is whole single item?

Comment: can you include `TextInputMask` and the a sample `value` for `item.amount` in the question? it's a parsing error

Comment: It only works when I add TextInputMask. Does not work with others.

Answer (score 0):

try this: replace `subtitle` for `ListItem` with:

```
subtitle={
  <div>
    <TextInputMask
      type={'money'}
      options={{ precision: 2, separator: ',', delimiter: '.', unit: '' }}
      value={parseFloat(item.amount)}
    />
    {'Count: ' + item.count}
  </div>
}
```

Comment: `[object Object]` what is the actual value that produces this text?

Comment: string "222.55" like that

Comment: Can you include TextInputMask component code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding and integer to an Object so that's why it displays it like that. TextInoutMask component takes suffixUnit as a props you can give the value of your item.count directly there.

```
<TextInputMask
  type={'money'}
  options={{ precision: 2, separator: ',', delimiter: '.', unit: '', suffixUnit: `Count: ${item.count}` }}
  value={parseFloat(item.amount)}
/>
```

Comment: This is irrelevant. You can translate a number in the Value section. You are adding a string. It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Change to one with return value.

```js
<FlatList
  data={teams}
  renderItem={({item}) =>
    <ListItem
      title={item.team}
      subtitle={
        MaskService.toMask('money',parseFloat(item.amount), {
    unit: '',
    precision: 2,
    separator: ',',
    delimiter: '.'
}) + 'Count: ' + item.count
      }
      bottomDivider={true}
    />
  }
  keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
/>
```